# Constant reboot after setting up the Global Descriptor Table and protected mode

Tags: x86, bootloader, osdev, protected-mode, gdt

I must have done something wrong with the `GDT setup` and the switch to `protected mode` because it keeps constantly rebooting.

Here is my `kernel.asm` that should setup the `GDT` and switch to `protected mode`:

```
    bits 16

    jmp main
    %include "gdt.inc"

    main:
        cli
        xor ax,ax
        mov ds,ax
        mov es,ax
        mov ax,0x9000
        mov ss,ax
        mov sp,0xffff
        sti

        call InstallGDT

        cli
        mov eax,cr0
        or eax,1
        jmp 08h:Stage3

    bits 32
    Stage3:

        mov ax,0x10
        mov ds,ax
        mov ss,ax
        mov es,ax
        mov esp,90000h

    Stop:

        mov byte [0xb8000],'A'
        cli
        hlt
```

and there is the `gdt.inc`:

```
bits 16
InstallGDT:

    cli
    pusha
    lgdt   [toc]
    sti
    popa
    ret
gdt_data:
    dd 0
    dd 0

    dw 0ffffh
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0

    dw 0ffffh
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
end_of_gdt:
toc:
    dw end_of_gdt - gdt_data -1
    dd gdt_data
```

My `bootloader.asm` loads 10 sectors  to `0x1000:0x000` and then jumps there.

I test the code with the commands:

```
nasm -f bin -o bootloader.bin bootloader.asm
nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin kernel.asm
cat bootloader.bin kernel.bin>OS.bin
qemu-system-i386 OS.bin
```

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 2):

Since I can only assume you have read the sectors into memory at 0x1000:0x0000 correctly I can only point out potential problems in `kernel.asm` and `gdt.inc`.

---

### Issues with the code

**If** you reached the kernel stage with `jmp 0x1000:0x0000` (I suspect this is the case) then in `kernel.asm` you incorrectly set the *DS*, and *ES* segment registers to the wrong value. In that case you will need to set those two registers to 0x1000, not 0x0000. This code:

```
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
```

needs to be changed to:

```
    mov ax,0x1000
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
```

---

The next major problem you have is that the [*GDT*](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/LGDT:LIDT.html) record (inside `toc`) takes a linear address. A linear address in real mode is the same thing as a physical address. From the instruction set manual it says:

> The source operand specifies a 6-byte memory location that contains the base address (**a linear address**) and the limit (size of table in bytes) of the global descriptor table (GDT)

You have used an *ORG* of 0x0000 (since you didn't specify one) for `kernel.asm` so *NASM* assumes all offsets generated are from a base of 0x0000 including the label `gdt_data`. So when you do this:

```
toc:
dw end_of_gdt - gdt_data -1
dd gdt_data
```

`gdt_data` will be some small offset just above 0x0000. In physical memory your *GDT* record is actually at 0x1000:0x0000+(small offset). 0x1000:0x0000 in physical (linear) memory is [(0x1000<<4)+0x0000](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) = 0x10000 so you need to add that to `gdt_data`. Your `toc` should look like this to compensate:

```
toc:
dw end_of_gdt - gdt_data -1
dd gdt_data+0x10000
```

---

The next issue you have is that you don't actually switch the protected mode flag on. You have this:

```
    mov eax,cr0
    or eax,1
```

It should be:

```
    mov eax,cr0
    or eax,1
    mov cr0, eax
```

You need to update the protected mode bit in the *CR0* register after you set the bit to 1.

---

Related to the *GDT* issue, you have created *GDT* entries for the code segment from an offset of 0x00000000 which encompass the entire 4gb address space. This is correct. Again though, since *NASM* created offset from 0x0000 and your code is actually loaded at 0x1000:0x0000 (physical address 0x10000) you need to add 0x10000 to the value of `stage3` label in the *JMP* that finally sets up protected mode. As well, because we are encoding a value that is above 0xFFFF we need to force *NASM* to use a 32-bit operand so we use the `dword` qualifier on the `JMP`. You have this:

```
jmp 08h:Stage3
```

It should be this:

```
jmp dword 08h:Stage3+0x10000
```